# Render SolidJS component based on get parameter

Tags: solid-js

I have a simple SolidJS component:

```js
export const PageContent: Component<{content: string}> = (props) => {
    
}
```

Now, since I would like to build a web app with many pages, and I would like to keep things like header, footer, nav, etc. the same across all pages, I thought that I could customize what it is displayed by `PageContent` based on a get parameter, like: `https://my-app.com?content=home` or `...?content=customers`, ...

To keep thinks clean, I'd like to define a component for each possible value of the get parameter (i.e., for every page) in a separate folder (like: `content/Home.tsx`, `content/Customers.tsx`, etc.).

Can I return the appropriate component in `PageContent` based on the get parameter (with the content prop)?
Or there is a better way to do what I want to do?

I'm new to Solid and used to work with PHP-based websites, this is why the idea of the get parameter came to my mind (recalling `index.php?page=`).

Thanks

(I tried searching returning `<props.content></props.content>` but it didn't work.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to go using a router library like solid-js router. SolidJS Router lets you change your view based on the URL in the browser like you asked for. We use path instead of get parameters to match request to the page or component to display, however the logic is totally up to you weather to use query parameters or paths or any other request based value. It support wildcard routes to blanket match previously unmatched urls.

https://github.com/solidjs/solid-router

```js
import { Routes, Route } from "@solidjs/router"

const Home = () => {
  return (<div>Home</div>);
};

const Users = () => {
  return (<div>Users</div>);
};

export default function App() {
  return <>
    <h1>My Pages</h1>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/users" component={Users} />
      <Route path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" element={<div>This site was made with Solid</div>} />
    </Routes>
  </>
}
```

Note: Currently SolidJS Playground does not support solid-js router, you need to use codesandbox or set your own local environment.

Comment: Sure, forgot to do that, sorry